# How do you do LoD in DirectX and C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, directx, models

I have a 4 cells loaded up and I want to know how to make it so it displays with low detail. Anyone have any idea on how to do that? I don't need you to do the distance and stuff like that. Just tell me how to put a cell into a low LoD.

Comment: Render it to a small texture, then stretch the texture to a screen-sized quad?

Comment: uhh.. I'm not talking about doing that. I want to make it so the definition of the cube is very low.

Comment: I think most engines use actual different models for different LoD and switch between them based on their Z coordinate in the scene. Another approach would be to use tesselation. i think it was introduced in DX11. As far as the textures go - you can generate mipmaps and the GPU will pick the appropriate level

Comment: okay well if i had a giant landscape made up of 4 cells, how would I do LoD on that?

Comment: @Gir: yeah, but..... this question asks about a cube, which already has the minimum number of vertices.

Comment: forget about the cube guys. I got the answer for that. How can i do LoD on terrain?

Comment: @dvds414: Change your question to not be about a cube. Use the "edit" button under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(With basic dirextX function)

For texture, use IDirect3DBaseTexture9::SetLOD
For mesh, see directx sample named ProgressiveMesh or Tessellation

Comment: Thank you for the useful information on texture LoD, but do you know anything about LoD on big landmasses with 4 cells?

Comment: I'm not sure , but what you mean by 4 cells ?

Comment: I made a really big landscape but split it into 4 big cells. I wanna make it so if I stand on a mountain it makes it so the cells far away are barely rendered and theres gonna be some fog after a while. But I want to make it so there is LoD on things far away

Comment: By my understanding. LOD is usually applied only on texture or mesh.For texture it means mipmap. For mesh it means reducing the count of triangles. What you want to do is most likely scene management. So you may collect the objects far away, and then do LOD operation on them.

Comment: My landscape is a mesh though.

Comment: And if you want to remesh the landscape which divided by 'cell'. You may need something more than DirectX library.

Comment: I'm just trying to optimize the terrain, thats all

Comment: Ok, sorry for my misunderstanding. Then I think maybe you need something like this. http://vterrain.org/LOD/Implementations/

Comment: well uhh.. thanks im not looking for another engine though because i am making my own

Comment: I just mean you might find some re-meshing algorithm there. ( I don't think there is a good method to do real-time re-mesh on a arbitrary terrain mesh )

Comment: I saw some guy do it in a video real time perfectly.

Comment: well. I just mean structure of terrain mesh is mostly related to re-mesh algorithm so that can be optimized. Since you are developing your own engine, most likely you need to write your own algorithm. btw, if 'cell' is a single mesh then ProgressiveMesh will do. If cell is part of whole terrain mesh, maybe you could just split it and then do mesh reduce.